# Ionic ,Node js build ios error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a basic mobile app using steps provided on
[this link](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

Everything worked fine till step 3. But on step 3

```
$ ionic build ios
```

is giving error as under

> ✗ (node:9776) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not
> supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it
> to a more recent version.
>
> Error: xcodebuild was not found. Please install version 6.0.0 or
> greater from App Store

[image: Error Image]

I am already using the latest version of node.js ie; 6.2.0. Am I missing anything?

Comment: As per the error, you need to install xcodebuild version 6 or greater.

Comment: You can't compile to iOS using Windows, unless of course someone's written a port of `xcodebuild`

Comment: @theaccordance - Well spotted, I overlooked that...

Comment: When the error says "more recent version" it refers to graceful-fs , not Node itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can't compile iOS apps locally using a Windows Machine.  You'll either need to compile those apps using a Mac, or a cloud-compiler service, like [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) or [Ionic Platform](http://ionic.io/platform).

Comment: ionic is what i am trying to use...How to build it using ionic?

Comment: You'll have to read how to do it on Ionic's website.  I don't use their cloud compiler because I develop on a Mac